# TheBat plugin api - how to get new mail notifications?

Tags: api, email, plugins, pascal

Each time when TheBat recieving new email I need to do some action in my custom plugin. From the plugin API [documentation](https://www.ritlabs.com/download/files3/the_bat/doc/thebat-api-doc-1-1.rar) as far as I understand I need to use `ITBPCoreBridge` interface for getting access to most TheBat functions. But there`s no details how to use it. I guess I need `RegisterNotification` method, but I don`t know what`s next.

Comment: Generally, calling into an API is a lot easier that getting a call-back notification from it.  Try writing a textual specification of what you want to achieve by interacting with the API and then ponder how to get a hand-hold on the API to do it.

Comment: Okay. I don\`t like ThaBat\`s Mail Ticker and want to simple show popup baloon when new mail recieved. I didn`t found how to do this in ThaBat or any similar plugin. So I want to implement this by myself using free pascal.